# applicationWillEnterForeground - go to rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to return to the rootviewcontroller when the app fires ApplicationWillEnterForeground?

I want to check a couple of parameters, and if the parameters fit, I should be "redirected" to the rootView, (like the app is starting up again...)

Comment: They are your view controllers, you can do whatever you want with them. Checkout popToRootViewController if you are using a navigation stack.

Comment: Do consider the usability concerns of your application. 

Would it make more sense to present a Login or PIN code screen modal for re-entry instead? This way the user does not lose their navigation stack.

Comment: Yes, Its usefull, the app would do this when there was at least 1 hour of inactivity. Found a solution, with the setRootViewController it worked!